# maven tomcat deploy plugin so that no rebuild is done

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-tomcat-plugin

I use jenkins to build my gwt app, now I want to run a tomcat:deploy on that built project so that it can deploy the built war to tomcat.

Problem is it insists on doing a package beforehand even though the package was just done.

This causes a gwt recompile - this takes a *Very* long time.

Is there a way I can invoke a deploy to tomcat with maven that will simply deploy an already existing war?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [deploy-only](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat6-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html) goal, which won't invoke the `package` build lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Mre generally, check out the list of [Maven Tomcat Plugin Goals](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)

Doing a sequence of

```
mvn tomcat:undeploy
mvn tomcat:deploy-only
```

is essentially a "redeploy without building" which you sometimes want to do to see what happens at startup. Although if you really just want to see the webapp start up, there's

```
mvn tomcat:reload
```